# Counting number of duplicate attributes of an ArrayList of objects of the same type

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a class that evaluates each Poker player's two dealt cards and five table cards together and returns the number of duplicates found. For example if a player is dealt an Ace and a Two and the table is Ace, Three, Four, Ace, Five, it should return "Player 1 had three aces". This is what I have so far, it's accurate about fifty percent of the time, but sometimes it misses that the player had multiple pairs or miscounts how many duplicates there were. [Here](https://pastebin.com/zV4Z63BC) is an example console output

```
package edu.sbcc.cs105;

import java.util.*;

public class Evaluate {
    ArrayList<Card> sevenCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    int player;
    String faces[] = { "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King",
            "Ace" };

    public Evaluate(Card c1, Card c2, Card c3, Card c4, Card c5, Card c6, Card c7, int p) {
        sevenCards.clear();
        sevenCards.add(c1);
        sevenCards.add(c2);
        sevenCards.add(c3);
        sevenCards.add(c4);
        sevenCards.add(c5);
        sevenCards.add(c6);
        sevenCards.add(c7);
        this.player = p;
        duplicateFaces(sevenCards);
    }

    public void duplicateFaces(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
        int duplicateCount = 0;
        String card = "";
        ArrayList<String> dupCards = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < cards.size(); j++) {
                if ((cards.get(i).getFace()).equals(cards.get(j).getFace())) {
                    if (!dupCards.contains(cards.get(j).getFace())) {
                        duplicateCount++;
                        dupCards.add(cards.get(j).getFace());
                        card = cards.get(j).getFace();
                    }
                }
            }
            dupCards = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        if (duplicateCount > 1) {
            returnDuplicates(duplicateCount, card);
        }
    }

    public void returnDuplicates(int count, String card) {
        System.out.println("Player " + player + " had " + count + " " + card + "s");
    }
}
```

Comment: You only have one instance of `duplicateCount` that is shared between all card faces, and what is the purpose of `if (!dupCards.contains(cards.get(j).getFace()))`, it will only count duplicates the first time it finds them, but what about if you have three of the same card? Consider using a Hashmap with the card face as the key, and the value as the count, this way you can easily track each card face, and increment the count as required

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you only have one instance of `duplicateCount` and `card` variables that are shared between all card faces, this will not work. Also this line `if (!dupCards.contains(cards.get(j).getFace()))` will only count duplicates the first time it finds them, but what about if you have three of the same card?

Here is a solution with comments that uses a `Hashmap` with the card face as the key, and the value as the count, this way you can easily track each card face with a single `for` loop and increment the count as required:

```
//Use a hashmap to store the cards
HashMap<String, Integer> results = new HashMap<>();

//Updated method to count duplicates
public void duplicateFaces(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
    //Use a single loop and update each card in the hashmap
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        //Incriment count of duplicate card if found
        if (results.containsKey(cards.get(i).getFace())) {
            results.get(cards.get(i).getFace())++;
        }
        //Else enter new card with value of 1 (No duplicates yet)
        else {
            results.put(cards.get(i).getFace(), 1);
        }
    }
    //Now print the duplicates
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : results.entrySet())
    {
        //Print out any cards that are found more than once
        if (entry.getValue() > 1){
            returnDuplicates(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }
    }
}

//Existing print method
public void returnDuplicates(int count, String card) {
    System.out.println("Player " + player + " had " + count + " " + card + "s");
}
```